# Oracle SQL - Time difference within multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, time, plsql

I have a case where I have a event log with millions of log entires, let's call the table "Event_hist". "Event_hist" is populated by event parameters from another table, called "Cases" which is only containing the last event/status.

I need to find time usage in minutes between two log entries within different departments based on when the department and only for certain case types.

| Log_ID | Case_ID | Dep_ID | Case_type | Creation_TS | Log_TS | Log_txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 91 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | Case opened |
| 2 | 1002 | 91 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:05 | 2021-09-02 10:05 | Case opened |
| 3 | 1003 | 93 | 2 | 2021-09-02 10:07 | 2021-09-02 10:07 | Case opene |
| 4 | 1001 | 91 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | 2021-09-02 10:08 | Case halted |
| 5 | 1001 | 91 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | 2021-09-02 10:10 | Transferred to dep 93 |
| 6 | 1001 | 93 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | 2021-09-02 10:11 | Case opened |
| 7 | 1002 | 91 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:05 | 2021-09-02 10:20 | Case processed |
| 8 | 1001 | 93 | 1 | 2021-09-02 10:00 | 2021-09-02 10:31 | Case processed |
| 9 | 1003 | 93 | 2 | 2021-09-02 10:07 | 2021-09-02 10:54 | Case processed |

Result wanted:

| Case_ID | Dep_ID | Time_used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 91 | 10 |
| 1001 | 93 | 21 |
| 1002 | 91 | 15 |

```
Select
eh.case_id,
eh.dep_id,
round((eh.log_ts-eh.creation_ts)*1440,0) as time_used
From event_hist eh
Left join Cases C on eh.Case_id = c.Case_id
where eh.creation_ts > date '2021-09-01'
and eh.case_type=1
and eh.log_id=select(max(log_id) from event_hist where case_id=app.case_id)
```

The result I am getting is understably the time difference between the last log entry for the case_id vs Creation_TS (I think).
How can I factor Dep_ID in this query and get the result as wanted?

Comment: I think you have a typo in the select, after creation_ts) it appears `' ` , but I think you meant `* `

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query would answer your question:

```sql
SELECT case_id, dep_id, ROUND((MAX(log_ts)-MIN(log_ts))*1440, 0)
FROM event_hist eh
WHERE eh.case_type = 1
GROUP BY case_id, dep_id
ORDER BY case_id, dep_id;
```

Here is a DBFiddle showing your test data ([LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=975897e53f58baaf41f97362216acfa0))